# SQL Multi Innerjoin

Tags: sql

Hello in my system i have a search page for a student that the admin will be able to view
the students history i have a problem with showing the last name of his/her adviser which is lname_A. This is the code i currently us so far everything is ok except i cant manage to get the lname_a.

```
    $qry_display = "SELECT
        a.student_id, a.section_id, a.level, a.photo, a.address, a.father_occupation, a.father_phone, a.father_company, a.mother_occupation, a.mother_phone, a.mother_company,a.gpa,
        b.fname, b.sex, b.lname, b.mname, b.birth_date, b.birth_place, b.address, b.father, b.father_degree, b.mother, b.mother_degree,
        c.section_name, d.adviser_id , d.lname_a
        FROM tbl_er AS a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_enroll AS b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_section AS c ON a.section_id = c.section_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_adviser AS d ON a.section_id = d.adviser_id
        WHERE a.student_id=".$id." AND a.level='Grade 2'";
```

Would gladly appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry i mean i cant manage to show the lname, its blank.

Comment: Blank value for d.adviser and lname_a is not blank.

Comment: Build it up step by step. What does `"SELECT * FROM tbl_er WHERE student_id=".$id." AND level='Grade 2'"` give you? Then add in the ONE left join that doesn't seem to work, what does that give you? Taking it step by step you can see where it breaks. Then you need to either check that part of the query or the data that you are joining to see if data you *think* exists actually doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you are joining both tables or correct columns?
a.section_id = d.adviser_id

Answer (score 0):

If every student has adviser then you should use inner join rather than left outer join.

When you use left outer join there is chance lname_a is empty when the student doesn't has adviser.